# Splatting after passing hashtable by reference in Powershell

Tags: powershell, hashtable, pass-by-reference

I ran into a snag when I passed a hash table by reference to a function for splatting purposes. How can I fix this?

```
Function AllMyChildren {
    param (
        [ref]$ReferenceToHash
    }
    get-childitem @ReferenceToHash.Value
    #  etc.etc.
}
$MyHash = @{
    'path' = '*'
    'include' = '*.ps1'
    'name' = $null
}
AllMyChildren ([ref]$MyHash)
```

> Result: an error (*"Splatted variables cannot be used as part of a property or array expression. Assign the result of the expression to a temporary variable then splat the temporary variable instead."*).

Tried to do this:

```
$newVariable = $ReferenceToHash.Value
get-childitem @NewVariable
```

That did work and seemed right per the error message. Is it the *preferred* syntax in a case like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Passing hashtables (or any instances of classes, i.e. reference types) with `[ref]` makes no sense because they are always passed by reference themselves. `[ref]` is used with value types (scalars and instances of structures).

2) The splatting operator can be applied to a variable directly, not an expression.

Thus, in order to resolve the problem simply pass the hashtable in the function as it is:

```
Function AllMyChildren {
    param (
        [hashtable]$ReferenceToHash # it is a reference itself
    )
    get-childitem @ReferenceToHash
    #  etc.etc.
}
$MyHash = @{
    'path' = '*'
    'include' = '*.ps1'
    'name' = $null
}
AllMyChildren $MyHash
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I _was_ thinking Perl-ish (and not .Net-ish enough -- lots to learn). It seemed very odd to pass something explicitly by reference and yet to have to make a copy of it. Glad to hear it's much more straightforward than I'd thought.